# How to use different libraries for different devices in Ionic Framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

For example, I want to use `angular-material.js` only in my Android template:

**THIS LOADS FOR EVERYBODY**

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

**THIS LOADS FOR ANDROID ONLY, NOT FOR IOS**

```
<script src="lib/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```